# REACT a button that updates state which updates the button value

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-state

i have this state to check if the user added a specific item to shopping cart or no:

```
  const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);
```

in the beginning, it assumes user didn't add the item to his shopping cart so the value of the button will be `ADD TO CART`

```
            <button
              type="button"
              className="addToCart"
              onClick={() => handleCart(item._id)}
            >
              {isAdded ? "REMOVE FROM CART" : "ADD TO CART"}
            </button>
```

when the user clicks ```ADD TO CART`` it trigger this function:

```
  const handleCart = async (itemId) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8000/add-or-remove-item-from-cart/${itemId}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: user._id,
        }),
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setIsAdded(!isAdded);
  };
```

the function make request to `http://localhost:8000/add-or-remove-item-to-cart/${itemId}` and checks if the user already added this item to his shopping cart it will remove it, otherwise it will add it, and this works like a charm

the button value should update immediately when the user clicks to add or remove the item from his/her shopping cart and also should be updated when page gets refresh, so when he clicks it will change `isAdded` state to the opposite `setIsAdded(!isAdded);` , but this doesn't work as **useEffect** is must needed to check if user added item to his shopping cart or no and update state accordingly, it will look like something like this:

```
const { user } = useContext(AuthContext); // user coming from context API

useEffect(()=>{
  setIsAdded(user.cartItems.includes(itemId)) // true if user added the item, false otherwise
},[itemId])
```

but the problem is i don't have access to `itemId` in `useEffect` as i also can't use it inside the `handleCart` function, so how can i do that to persist state ?

Comment: You should pass the itemId as a prop in the ItemCard(if you are showing a list of items) or as a part of url(dynamic routing if the button is in item details page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate component ItemCard and pass itemId as props to this ItemCard.

```
    const ItemCard = ({itemId})=>{
        const { user } = useContext(AuthContext); // user coming from context API

        useEffect(()=>{
            setIsAdded(user.cartItems.includes(itemId)) // true if user added 
            //the item, false otherwise
        },[itemId]);
        return <button
          type="button"
          className="addToCart"
          onClick={() => handleCart(item._id)}
        >
          {isAdded ? "REMOVE FROM CART" : "ADD TO CART"}
        </button>
    }
```

Then when you are showing the list of items, do this

```
items.map((item)=> <ItemCard key={item.itemId} itemId={item.itemId} ...item/>)
```